# How save text like html input php sql var

Tags: html, input

This code

```
sari  =$POST->format_html($POST->post['sari']);
```

//
But not work

Comment: This looks like Django to me ..   We are going to need more information to better assist with the issue you are having ..  If you cannot provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it becomes exceedingly hard to help out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.